# Extracting from Sharepoint using Python and REST api

Tags: python, sharepoint, rest

What is meaning of `{0}/{1}` in `http://server/site/{0}/{1}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle`

Comment: I think it's formatting place holders

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I din't understand.

Comment: Try `"http://server/site/{0}/{1}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle".format("value for 1st place holder", "value for second place holder")` in your python interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{0}/{1}` should be placeholders.

[Python String format() Method:The Placeholders](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here, Brace characters ('curly braces') are used to indicate [replacement fields](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#format-strings) within the string:

Let's say you have this string,

```
my_string = "http://server/site/{0}/{1}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle"
```

and later in the code you can supply values for this replacement fields with string format function.

```
>>> my_string.format("first", "second")
'http://server/site/first/second/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle'
```

Here `{0}` will gets replaced with the first argument to the format function(`first`) and `{1}` will gets replaced with the second argument to the format function(`second`)

Comment: I am reading someone else's code "http://server/site/{0}/{1}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('x%20y')/Items" ..

so does it mean :  http://server/site/x/y/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('x%20y')/Items

Comment: Do you have link to github?

Comment: it is private .. sorry

Comment: Ok, Most probably some where on the code they will be using `.format` method to apply the replacement to  `{0}` and `{1}`